# How can I pass variables from JavaScript to PHP?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

I am using jQuery to calculate prices. Here is a small snippet of my JavaScript:

```
// Prices: radio
var curLam = "gloss";
$("input[name=lamination]").click(function () {
    var gloss = 5;
    var matt = 6;
    if ($(this).val() == 'gloss' && curLam != 'gloss') {
        $('#prices span').text(parseInt($('#prices span').text()) + gloss - matt);
        curLam = 'gloss';
        console.log('1');
    }
    if ($(this).val() == 'matt' && curLam != 'matt') {
        $('#prices span').text(parseInt($('#prices span').text()) - gloss + matt);
        curLam = 'matt';
        console.log('2');
    }
    $("#prices span").each(function () {
        var $priceValue = $(this);
    })
});
```

This checks to see if a matte or gloss finish has been selected and then it inserts the price into the `span` within the `prices` `div` tag.

I need to know how to assign that price value into a variable which can then be passed on to PHP for my shopping cart.

Answer (score 13):

Generally speaking, you shouldn't return the selected price to the server. HTML forms can be easily faked. It is far safer to send the user's **choice** back to the server, which also knows how much it should cost.

Basically Javascript validation (which this essentially is) is convenient but shouldn't be trusted. You already have an input for selecting the finish. Just send that back to the server. That way your site will still work (or work better) if the user has Javascript disabled.

Answer (score 1):

You could put the ID of the product into an input element and then when you submit into the shopping cart, then the value should be in your php $_POST variables.

There you can check the price and other information straight from your database.

Comment: but then oculd people change the values which would mean they cod effectively change the cost of items