# Send a var from js to php

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I pass variables from JavaScript to PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/980770/how-can-i-pass-variables-from-javascript-to-php)

When I do click a button it creates a variable $var and then I want to send this var to php to process it.

example:

### in Jquery.js

```
$('#button').click(function(){

//create the var
$name = "abcde";

//send the $name to process.php
---I DONT KNOW HOW---
});
```

### in process.php

just...

```
echo $name;
```

How to send the $name???

Comment: You want to send a var from JS to PHP? Use Ajax or submit a hidden form.

Comment: This question is asked 100 times a day, please search.

Comment: @nickb - I think he is new here, and we should instruct him how to search things up in SO.

Comment: @Derek - You mean how to type what you're looking for in the box that says "Search" and then hit enter? If that's the case, I hope Google comes with a user manual.

Comment: @nickb Yes there is a manual for Google Search :P [here](http://support.google.com/websearch/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=134479)

Answer (score 2):

You need to [POST](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POST_%28HTTP%29) it to the server, which PHP can pick up using `$POST['variablename']`.  This is usually done through including it in a form, or asynchronosly using [AJAX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29).

Answer (score 2):

### GET

```
$.get("url", {name: "abcde"}, function(response){
    //Do something
});
```

### POST

```
$.post("url", {name: "abcde"}, function(response){
    //Do something
});
```

Answer (score 0):

in jquery code

```
$.post('process.php',name:$name,function(data){alert(data);});
```

in process.php

```
if(isset($_POST['name'])){
  echo $_POST['name'];
}else{
  echo 'nothing was send';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#button').click(function(){
    var $name = "abcde";
    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: process.php,
      data: {name:$name},
      success: function(data){alert("send ok")}
    });
});
```

process.php:

```
if(isset($_POST['name'])){
  echo $_POST['name'];
}
```