# How to assign javascript value to php variable without using cookie

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am recieving data form controller in ajax. Then I should assign it to php variable but without using cookies. How to do it?
My code:

```
$.ajax({
        url: '/controller/action',
        type: 'post',
        data: {
            id: id,
        },
        success: function(data){
            if (data) {
                //here I should assign data to php variable
            }
            if (!data) {
                console.log('no data');
            }
        }

     });
```

Comment: You can't assign a JS variable to a PHP variable, JS is client side, PHP is server side, you can assign a PHP value to JS by echoing the variable into the JS (e.g. `var myvar = '<?= $phpvar; ?>';`), but not the other way around

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I pass variables from JavaScript to PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/980770/how-can-i-pass-variables-from-javascript-to-php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try using this demo code

```
<script>
if (data) {
    var a =data;
    <?php $abc = "<script>document.write(a)</script>"?>   
}
if (!data) {
    console.log('no data');
}
</script>
<?php
   echo $abc;
?>
```

Comment: try it bro and than tell @SamSwift웃

Answer (score 0):

you can create a link with JavaScript that includes a GET variable. ones clicked php gets involved

**code**:
http://example.org/index.php?q1=blablabla

**Php code:**

`if(isset($_GET['q1']) {$ff = $_GET['q1']}`